# Implode a simplexml output

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, implode

I need to output what is outputted from the foreach loop that I am using, without the extraneous array tags surrounding it. An example of some output that I have is...

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [type] => text
        )

    [0] => SMEs spend Â£6.89bn on unused technology
)
```

The code I am using to output the above is below

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://news.telecomsworldplc.co.uk/atom.xml');
echo "<pre>";
foreach($xml->entry as $entry){
    foreach($entry->title as $title){
        print_r($title);
    }
}
echo "</pre>";
```

The output needs to be just "SMEs spend Â£6.89bn on unused technology"... Would it be implode I use?

Thanks!

Comment: No, you can access that part of the array with `$title[0]`.

Comment: Hi there, tried changing to `print_r($title[0]);` but it outputs the same.

Comment: Don't use `print_r()`, as that outputs an array into readable format. Use `echo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code, It's working here

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://news.telecomsworldplc.co.uk/atom.xml');
echo "<pre>";
foreach($xml->entry as $entry){ 
    foreach($entry->title as $key=>$title){
        print_r($key." => ".$title. "<br/>");
    }
}
echo "</pre>";
exit;
```

Comment: Nice one, thanks! Didn't need the "title =>" bit, but that was easily changed. Thanks a lot :)